React Component - wait for prior promise method (fetch) to reach its finally {} block (cancelled using AbortController) before starting a new promise
I have a React component with 3 buttons representing 3 choices the user can make.
If the user clicks a button and then another button I cancel the previous HTTP request using AbortController.signal.abort(), it is really incredibly simple.
The thing is, the method has a loading state in its try {} catch {} finally {} block.
When I cancel the first promise the http request is really cancelled but the second promise starts to run before the first promise reaches its finally scope.. making the loader -> false before the second promise finished.

first click -> first promise runs
another click -> second promise runs
first HTTP is cancelled
new request starts
finally {} block of the first function invoked/runs
finally {} block of the second function invoked/runs

I tried doing it in 2 ways:
First Way

export default function SingleTesterQuestion({
  question,
}: {
  question: SomeType;
}) {
  const controller = useRef(new AbortController());
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const updateQuestionInServerForSpecificId = useCallback(
    async (choice: string) => {
      try {
        // if same question with same id got clicked on
        // different buttons (fast) abort the previous request
        controller.current.abort();
        controller.current = new AbortController();
        setLoading(true);
        await httpMethods.answerSimulationTestQuestion(
          question.id,
          choice,
          controller.current.signal
        );
        // update some store
      } catch (error) {
        //
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    },
    [question.id]
  );
  return (
    <Box>
      <Choices updateQuestionInServerForSpecificId={updateQuestionInServerForSpecificId} />
    </Box>
  );
}


Second Way (trying to add some fuction in the middle that uses signal.onabort())

export default function SingleTesterQuestion({
  question,
}: {
  question: SomeType;
}) {
 const controller = useRef<null | AbortController>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const req = async (choice: string) => {
    try {
      // if same question with same id got clicked on
      // different buttons (fast) abort the previous request
      controller.current = new AbortController();
      setLoading(true);
      await httpMethods.answerSimulationTestQuestion(
        question.id,
        choice,
        controller.current.signal
      );
      // update some store
    } catch (error) {
      //
    } finally {
      controller.current = null;
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const updateQuestionInServerForSpecificId = async (
    choice: string
  ) => {
    if (!controller.current) {
      // no one has yet to create an AbortController
      // make the request here
      await req(choice);
      return;
    }

    // there is already an AbortController out there
    controller.current.signal.onabort = async (x) => {
      await req(choice);
    };

    controller.current.abort();
  };
  return (
    <Box>
      <Choices updateQuestionInServerForSpecificId={updateQuestionInServerForSpecificId} />
    </Box>
  );
}


That's the method:
  async answerSimulationTestQuestion(
    questionId: string,
    choice: string,
    signal: GenericAbortSignal
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    const { data } = await axios.put<boolean>(
      `url...`,
      { choice },
      { params: { questionId }, signal }
    );
    return data;
  }

Is there anyway to solve this? Why is this happening?

I would use a counter instead of a boolean. I would start the state at 0 and increment by 1 inside the try, decrement by 1 inside the finally. The isLoading variable would then be count > 0

I think this will prevent the state change:
        finally {
        if (!controller.current.signal.aborted) 
           setLoading(false);
        }


Hi, thank you for your help, this didn't work for me though.. I think it's because the finally {} scope of the first promise gets the new AbortConroller.signal.aborted that is currently running (the new one), and it's always false and never true.

The AbortController.abort() will trigger the catch block. I'd check there if the error was caused by an 'AbortError' and only set the loading state to false whenever the the error is caused by something different.
The setLoading(false) in the finally block can be  moved to after the await line, for you only want it to do that on a successful request, or an error caused other than by your AbortController.
const controller = useRef<null | AbortController>(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const updateQuestionInServerForSpecificId = useCallback(
  async (choice: string) => {
    try {
      if (controller.current !== null) {
        controller.current.abort();
      }

      controller.current = new AbortController();
      setLoading(true);

      await httpMethods.answerSimulationTestQuestion(
        question.id,
        choice,
        controller.current.signal
      );

      controller.current = null;
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name !== 'AbortError') {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  },
  [question.id]
);

Let me know if this works for I haven't been able to test it.
